# Parse txt file displayed into tables in php/html

Tags: php, css, parsing

I've just created a script to grab the ip, hostname, and date and put into a text file. I wanted to create another script to display this information into a .php with some tables to make it easy to read.

This is the code I'm using to write to the file it works perfect. I just don't know how to parse it to do what I want it to do.

```
$logFile = 'IPLog.txt';
$fh = fopen($logFile,'a') or die("can't open file");
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$fullhost = gethostbyaddr($ip);
$stringData = date('m/d/y | h:ia') . " - " . $ip . ":" . $fullhost . "\n";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh);
```

The output looks like this..

04/06/13 | 02:53pm - xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxx.comcast.net

I'm waiting the script to read the file and display it in tables such as.

```
IP Address      | Hostname          | Date        | Time
----------------|-------------------|-------------|-----------------------------
xxx.xxx.xxx.xx  | xxx.comcast.net   | 04/06/13    | 02:53pm
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
xxx.xxx.xxx.xx  | xxx.comcast.net   | 04/06/13    | 02:53pm
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
xxx.xxx.xxx.xx  | xxx.comcast.net   | 04/06/13    | 02:53pm
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
xxx.xxx.xxx.xx  | xxx.comcast.net   | 04/06/13    | 02:53pm
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So I want it to just make a nice little table to display the information so I can just check it real fast and it looks nice.

There isn't any particular reason why I want this. I am only using this for an example of how to parse a text file. I have never been good at it and really want to learn how it's done. So I could use this for other things if I wanted too.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) Show us some PHP/HTML code. Check the [html table](http://www.quackit.com/html/html_table_tutorial.cfm) structure. Also, do you want to append 'IPLog.txt' with the html table or that was just a mistake?

Comment: Your desired output should be an HTML `<table>` tag, or you want the ascii art style? I'm confused.

Comment: @complex857 I guessed html table until I saw that he was actually appending the current info to the .txt ... I'll wait for the OP to make it clear

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet to be honest I don't even know where to start. I have a script that saves the information into a txt file. That I want to pull the information out of the text file and display it into a table that can be read easier. Without having to download the txt file. The second code I have there is just what I want it to look like. I typed all that out it was a pain to make it look like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your current output to: `04/06/13 - 02:53pm - xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - www.comcast.net`.
This will make it more easier to parse later.
So in your current file you have to change the following line:

`$stringData = date('m/d/y - h:ia') . " - " . $ip . " - " . $fullhost . "\n";`

Now to display the data in a table you can use the following:

```
$logFile = 'IPLog.txt';
$lines = file($logFile); // Get each line of the file and store it as an array
$table = '<table border="1"><tr><td>Date</td><td>Time</td><td>IP</td><td>Domain</td></tr>'; // A variable $table, we'll use this to store our table and output it later !
foreach($lines as $line){ // We are going to loop through each line
    list($date, $time, $ip, $domain) = explode(' - ', $line);
    // What explode basically does is it takes a delimiter, and a string. It will generate an array depending on those two parameters
    // To explain this I'll provide an example : $array = explode('.', 'a.b.c.d');
    // $array will now contain array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd');
    // We use list() to give them kind of a "name"
    // So when we use list($date, $time, $ip, $domain) = explode('.', 'a.b.c.d');
    // $date will be 'a', $time will be 'b', $ip will be 'c' and $domain will be 'd'
    // We could also do it this way:
    // $data = explode(' - ', $line);
    // $table .= '<tr><td>'.$data[0].'</td><td>'.$data[1].'</td><td>'.$data[2].'</td><td>'.$data[3].'</td></tr>';
    // But the list() technique is much more readable in a way
    $table .= "<tr><td>$date</td><td>$time</td><td>$ip</td><td>$domain</td></tr>";
}
$table .= '</table>';
echo $table;
```

Comment: Wow I expected something way more coding then that. That's really simple going to study it really good and learn how that works. Thanks that's exactly what I wanted now I just need to clean it up with some css and make it look nice.

Comment: @JoeBobJr. You're welcome, I added comments in the code to explain what I did there, happy coding !